# R# - Possible incorrect implementation of Double-Check Locking pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, resharper

```
private readonly Object _syncRoot = new Object();
public IdGenerator ClientIdGenerator
{
    get
    {
        if ( clientIdGenerator != null )
            return clientIdGenerator;

        lock ( _syncRoot )
        {
            if ( clientIdGenerator != null )
                return clientIdGenerator;

            return clientIdGenerator = ClientIdPrefix != null ? new IdGenerator( ClientIdPrefix ) : new IdGenerator();
        }
    }
}
```

R# displays a warning "Possible incorrect implementation of Double-Check Locking pattern. Read access to checked field" on the line creating the instance of IdGenerator.

R# does not display the warning after I changed the code to this:

```
public IdGenerator ClientIdGenerator
{
    get
    {
        if ( clientIdGenerator == null )
            lock ( _syncRoot )
            {
                if ( clientIdGenerator != null )
                    return clientIdGenerator;

                clientIdGenerator = ClientIdPrefix != null ? new IdGenerator( ClientIdPrefix ) : new IdGenerator();
            }
        return clientIdGenerator;
    }
}
```

Is anything wrong with the first example, or is R# displaying a "wrong" warning?

Comment: Your first version should work nicely. I strongly think that resharper code analysis engine is misleading in this case.

Comment: I thought so as well… thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version should work nicely, but just to avoid misunderstandings for part of code analysis engines or co-worker, you can use the standard pattern:

```
private readonly Object _syncRoot = new Object();
public IdGenerator ClientIdGenerator
{
    get
    {
        if (clientIdGenerator == null)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (clientIdGenerator == null)
                {
                    clientIdGenerator = ClientIdPrefix != null ? new IdGenerator(ClientIdPrefix) : new IdGenerator();
                }
            }
        }

        return clientIdGenerator;
    }
}
```

This way you make clear your intentions.